# Обработка onload image в случае с массивом картинок

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!
Есть массив картинок, которые надо выгрузить на страницу ОДНОВРЕМЕННО. Известно, что на загрузку одной картинки можно повесить обработчик, т.е.:

```
img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
 //действия после загрузки фото
}
img.src='foto.jpg';
```

Как быть в случае, если не одна картинка на загрузку, а несколько?
Заранее благодарен за ответ.
уточню для чего мне это надо:
нужно загрузить несколько картинок, чтоб всех их задействовать в анимации через animate и действие после загрузки фоток должно применяться ко ВСЕМ фоткам...

Answer (score 3):

```
function onload_img(){
 //действия после загрузки фото
}

for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
   imgs[i].onload = onload_img;
}
```

зы: одновременно у выас ну никак не получится ...

Comment: //действия после загрузки фото

Здесь стоит примерно такое:  

    if(++num == imgs.length){
        // загружены все фото
    }

Надо только не забыть определить num = 0 до функции.

Comment: СУПЕР!!!
большое спасибо и уважение...

Comment: Там слева от ответа галочка...